# Multiple select checkboxes, what user select combines it into one file

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm about to start a project at my school - We just wan't to clear out which way would be the best way to go. I will try to describe the solution we want to achieve.

**The Project:**
The project is about appending files into one, so we decided that we would like the user to select what things should be in the file by using checkboxes to select it.

We need to make multiple selection fields with checkboxes like this:

```
<p>Please make selection for which newspapers you would like to subscribe to: </p>
<form>
    <!-- This is the input fields which should be linked to separate files -->
    <input type="checkbox" name="NewYorkTimes" value="NewYorkTimes">New York Times
    <input type="checkbox" name="TheSun" value="TheSun">The Sun
    <input type="checkbox" name="TheWallStreetJournal" value="TheWallStreetJournal">The Wall Street Journal

</form>
```

Then from what the users select this should all be combined in to one file combining them as a list and with all the info from the separate files:

File: subscriptions_29102014_1119.txt

```
UserID: #1337
IP Address: 10.10.13.37

Subscriptions made on 29/10/2014

New York Times
29/10/2014 - 13:37
Obama will be ready to leave the throne when time comes.

The Sun
29/10/2014 - 13:38
The Beatles are back in London

The Wall Street Journal
29/10/2014 - 13:39
Twitter looses again
```

This was just an example to maybe describe to it to you.

I am not sure if you're getting my point, so to describe it again **read this**:
Lets say that in my webroot folder i got 10 different files all containing different info or settings, whatever, they definitely doesn't look the same. From the users selections in the checkboxes,the selected files should be combined into one file.

You could actually say it would work the same way as the costumize function for Twitter Bootstrap 3 at http://getbootstrap.com/customize - Where it then compile it in to one file.
[image]

I hope this clarifies it and you could come up with a suggestion on how to do something like this. I know a little PHP and would prefer it to be in PHP myself. What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think something like that should help you

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['files'])) {
    $content = "";
    foreach ($_POST['files'] as $file) {
        if (file_exists($file.".txt")) {
            $content .= file_get_contents($file.".txt");
        }
    }
    $filename = 'test-download.txt';


    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; "); 
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    echo $content;
}else{
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    <!-- This is the input fields which should be linked to separate files -->
    <input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="NewYorkTimes">New York Times
    <input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="TheSun">The Sun
    <input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="TheWallStreetJournal">The Wall Street Journal
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

it check for files selected in the checkbox list and combine their contents into one downloadable file

Comment: Wow surely that helps alot! Didn't expect you to write the code for me, but now you've done it - Thank you.!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear. I mean, it's clear what you want to do, but it's unclear what help you actually want. I hope this helps enough without writing the whole thing for you:

1. Submit the form to ... say... formhandler.php
2. formhandler.php reads the values from your submitted form. See [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)
3. Create a blank file. See [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)
4. Using the values from step 2, identify and append the relevant files to the file you created in step 3. See [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and either [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) or [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)
5. Output the file. See [readfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Comment: Well i don't really want you to write the entire code for me, but I'm just here for inputs on what could be the best way to do it. If that includes any code for me to understand it better then that is what it is. I get your answer and will read up on those, so thank you for letting me know about those functions and explaining the procedure.